# Call stack for "Uses First/FirstOrDefault/Last/LastOrDefault operation without OrderBy and filter ..." warnings?

Tags: logging, entity-framework-core, warnings

EF Core 5.0.5 logs the following:

```
Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
EventId: 10103
SpanId: 4d772cc84463cb4c
TraceId: d086e4d89efe374799fcebf1dd354a47
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000a78-000b-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /xxx/yyy
ActionId: 349a1893-80e4-4d19-9a60-44d1492988a4
ActionName: /xxx/yyy/Index

The query uses the 'First'/'FirstOrDefault' operator without 'OrderBy' and filter operators. This may lead to unpredictable results.
```

But without a call stack it is not very helpful.

Is there a way to get a call stack included? Alternatively is there a way to turn off logging of just this message?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get a call stack included?

No. And it won't help. But you can turn `Debug` level logging which will show the query being built.

> Alternatively is there a way to turn off logging of just this message?

Yes (like any other). The corresponding key is

[CoreEventId.FirstWithoutOrderByAndFilterWarning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.coreeventid.firstwithoutorderbyandfilterwarning?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreEventId.FirstWithoutOrderByAndFilterWarning);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0)

and code similar to this:

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
    .Ignore(CoreEventId.FirstWithoutOrderByAndFilterWarning)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use .Throw instead of .Ignore and the stack trace was exactly what I needed.